# Prevent link to be opened in external browser with WebChromeClient

Tags: android, android-studio

I've developed a small group of .html pages that are stored in a server.
My android app, using a webview with: **setWebChromeClient** loads these pages.
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 24

**The problem:** 
Everytime I need to load a new page, using a link in my .html page, the new page is opened in an external browser.

**Url Overriding**
I know about the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method, when we're using the setWebViewClient().
But unfortunately I can't use the normal webview. I need to use the WebChromeClient() because of some feature that only work with this one. (Like the input file)

**My doubt is...**
How can I override my URL to force them to load inside of the webChromeClient?
I tried this but with no luck:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // (...)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Comment: WebChromeClient doesn't contain the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method so you achieve this the way you are doing. Please check my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by : `But unfortunately I can't use the normal webview. I need to use the WebChromeClient() because of some feature that only work with this one` ?

Comment: Hi, because using the setWebViewClient(), the input type "file" in my .html page, to upload an image, doesn't work. It doesn't open the file chooser.
When I use the setWebChromeClient() it does. It opens normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following code to achieve this.

```
WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true); // This forces ChromeClient enabled.    

web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
         getWindow().setTitle(title); //Set Activity tile to page title.
    }
});

web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It works great! But when I use the setWebViewClient(), the input type "file" stop working. It doesn't open the file chooser for uploading an image.
This feature seems to work fine with setWebChromeClient(). Is there a way to accomplish both things? (Link inside of the webview and also the input file), or maybe a way of change the webview based on the URL I've clicked. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Yes, absolutely! I still have a problem about the file input. It doesn't work when I set the WebViewClient()

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't work.
I have a button "add service"... When clicked it navigates to a new page, with a form and a button to upload images. When I use the WebChrome, the link open inside of the webview (Your solution works great here!)
But the input file strop working, because I've used setWebViewClient()... And this 'normal' webview, doesn't accept the input file. :(

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! I solved the problem. Using this:https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Comment: @Wini, `webview.canGoBack()` and `webview.goBack()` to achieve intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an embedded mobile web application in an Android App making use of the `WebChromeClient` class and did not want to fiddle around with recompiling the APK.

While looking for the easiest `header();` solution (since the mobile web application is in php) I found out that using:

`header("Location: url.php", TRUE, 307);`

was a quick fix solution without recompiling the Android app.

This allowed the user to re-direct within the app without calling the web browser externally from my app.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34409405/5968320) is the link to the answer by Arindam Nayak where I got the idea from.